# Negate a matrix in haskell?

Tags: haskell

If I am using a [vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector) package, how can I get a negative of a matrix? Just "Minusing" it doesn't work.

So from:

```
 1 2 3
 3 4 5
 6 7 8
```

I want to get:

```
 -1 -2 -3
 -3 -4 -5
 -6 -7 -8
```

No, multiplying by -1 doesn't work either:

```
let m = fromList [[10,20,30], [11,12, 13]]
Prelude Data.Vector> :t m
m :: Vector [Integer]
Prelude Data.Vector> (-1)*m


<interactive>:1:3:
    No instance for (Num (Vector [Integer]))
      arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for (Num (Vector [Integer]))
    In the expression: 1
    In the first argument of `(*)', namely `(- 1)'
    In the expression: (- 1) * m
```

Comment: Try multiplying by `-1`.

Comment: It's called the vector package, but it is not a convenient linear algebra library! It is vector as in the random-access data structure. Haskellers use vector package when wanting very high performance. If you use it when *learning* haskell it will just be cumbersome.

Answer (score 11):

I think you are confused about the purpose of the vector library. The description of it is:

> An efficient implementation of Int-indexed arrays (both mutable and immutable), with a powerful loop optimisation framework .

So it is just an array class - if you want to perform matrix operations on it you will have to code the solutions yourself.

What you really want is to use a true matrix library. [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) is a library that does this. Firstly install it using the [hmatrix installation instructions](http://perception.inf.um.es/hmatrix/install.html).

This is how you would write your program using `hmatrix`:

```
> import Data.Packed.Matrix
> let matrix = (3><3)[1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8]
> mapMatrix negate matrix
(3><3)
 [ -1.0, -2.0, -3.0
 , -3.0, -4.0, -5.0
 , -6.0, -7.0, -8.0 ]
```

There are heaps of matrix operations with the library, just read the [Data.Packed.Matrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.12.0.1/doc/html/Data-Packed-Matrix.html) and the [Numeric.Container](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.12.0.1/doc/html/Numeric-Container.html#t%3aMul) docs

Comment: Well, that one is out of the question. In windows getting the "* Missing C libraries: gsl-0, blas, lapack" error when installing hmatrix with cabal...

Comment: @drozzy: Read the linked installation instructions for Windows. It's all covered in there.

Comment: Thanks, still borked on windows. I give up - sorry, it shouldn't be that hard :-(

Comment: @drozzy: unfortunately most haskell programmers use as their OS either a linux distribution such as Ubuntu or Mac OSX. Both have package management systems that automate the installation of libraries. Unfortunately that leaves windows users a bit neglected - installing libraries in windows is incredibly hard as compared to linux/mac osx. So I can understand you giving up on it :(

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `Data.Vector.map (* (-1))` ?

---

For a matrix defined as `m :: Vector [Integer]`, that is a `Data.Vector.Vector` of lists of Integers, you can

```
Data.Vector.map (Prelude.map negate) m
```

The outer `map` maps function `(Prelude.map negate)` over the vector. The inner `map` negates all elements of a list.

Comment: Nope that doesn't work. And even if it did - what the heck is the point of "Vector" package - if I still have to go through the pain in the ass of iterating through every single element to negate the matrix? I thought this was supposed to make Linear Algebra easier!

Comment: Instead of `(* (-1))`, use `negate`.

Comment: @hammar I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: `Prelude.map` is always imported. It's just `map` as you know it.

Comment: @drozzy: The `vector` package is for `Int`-indexed arrays, not vectors in the linear algebra sense. For that, you'll want a real linear algebra package. [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) looks promising, but I don't have any experience with it myself.

Comment: @drozzy: hammar suggests you use `Data.Vector.map negate`, instead of `Data.Vector.map (* (-1))`.

Comment: @drozzy: I wanted to be explicit that the first `map` is from the vector package and the second one from the base package. It's just to make things more readable. Alternatively, you could `import qualified Data.Vector as V` and the code above would be `V.map (map negate) m`. [See this for some details about imports](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Import).

Comment: @hammar Thanks, but hmatrix looks weird. For example - where is a "matrix" in there - and how would you negate that? It looks like some kind of specialized package, not lin. algebra.

Comment: To expand on what Tinctorius said, more generally, the "Prelude" is the module that is imported automatically, unless you explicitly choose *not* to import it. So all the functions that you think of as being "built in" (map, filter, `.`, `$`, `foldr`, `>>=`, etc.) are in the Prelude.